# Specifying random effects for simulation of categorical data

Tags: mixed-model, simulation

I am simulating data for an experimental design with two conditions. I specified the following multilevel model:

$$
y_{ijk} = \beta_0 + u_{0j} + v_{0k} + (\beta_1 + u_{1j} + v_{1k}) * X_1 + e_{ijk}
$$

where $y$ is the $i$th measurement of my dependent variable for subject $j$ and stimulus $k$. I am modeling a population intercept $\beta_0$ and population effect of my experimental manupilation $\beta_1$, as well as random effects on intercept and slopes, both for subjects and stimuli. I am using dummy-coding for $X_1$ where the reference class of my experimental design has $X_1$ set to $0$ and the alternative class to $1$.

Now, I am unsure how to add the terms up during my simulation process: For instance, if subject $j$ is in the reference condition (i.e., $X_1 = 0$), the entire slope-term (i.e., $\beta_1 + u_{1j} + v_{1k}$) would drop from the calculation for $y_{ijk}$, however, I still would want to include the random effects for slope, no? Because if not, I would exclude random slopes (interpreted as ~the cluster-specific reaction to the manipulation) for an entire group of subjects in my experimental design.